Explination for arcing noise coming from protected power tap devices?
For years now there has been a random occurrence that happens with seemingly any power tap device I have with protection circuitry in it where it will make a audible buzzing/arcing sound for a few seconds once in a while (like once every few days on average) and I would like to know what the most probable explanation(s) are for it.
The first time I had noticed it was as I was laying in bed, I heard a muffled arcing noise coming from my Tripp-Lite Isobar power tap. I found this concerning, so I removed it from use and later inspected the protection circuit board inside and found no evidence of burning/melting/arcing. There was no significant load being passed through the device, as is the case with all the situations below too.
Soon after, I noticed the same thing occurring with the replacement Isobar, so I began to wonder if it was specific to that model of power tap. I had another model of power tap with active protection circuitry I tried, Intermatic, and it eventually did it too. I had concluded it must be a local/building oddity.
Years later in a new home, miles away from the previous location, I began to notice it occurring again, first with the Isobars I had, and then coming from the APC Smart-UPS I now use instead. Curiously, it seemingly only occurs specifically from the protection device directly connected to the wall receptacle, never in downstream devices with protection circuits.
As for it being some sort of transient event, I am fairly confident, as in once case I happened to have a LED, dropping resistor and Triac circuit connected line-to-neutral after the power tap device with the protection circuitry. The Triac was off and the LED visibly dark, but when the buzzing started, the LED began to shimmer dimly in sync with the buzzing, and then went back off when the buzzing stopped.

I suspect many strange location-specific or building-specific audible noises are caused by LC resonances. If there are both inductive loads (e.g. motor, compressor) and capacitive loads in the same building and they happen to have the right natural frequencies, and coincidentally there happens to be a suitable excitation signal (current harmonics from some load currents), strange noises can be produced. Of course it depends on many unpredictable factors such as circuit topologies, mechanical constructions, connected loads, source impedances, so most are never explained.

I wouldn't think accidental LCs would make for acoustic transducers though. There is one possibility: film and ceramic capacitors can produce sound when driven with AC. What kind of power taps are these, do they contain filters? Do you have a datasheet or photos of what's inside? If surge protectors, I don't know that MOVs can produce noise -- but perhaps they do and someone can substantiate it?

@TimWilliams One story I've read online: a PC user has a "singing" (likely coil whine, but unsure) ATX power supply that occurs whenever a deep freezer's compressor starts operating in another room. The problem persists in spite of replacing the ATX PSU to different brands or models, thus, they believe their PC is "haunted". My interpretation: the PSU's transformer or ceramic capacitor receives an excitation signal from mains and sings. Signal is injected by the compressor, and is likely sustained by LC resonance. Singing EMC filter or MOV is an interesting option that I didn't consider...

X caps, and maybe a CMC, seem plausible explanations for that case. Oh, I suppose resonance, if it's giving a longer time constant, could be relevant: effectively it's more time spent at more voltage [magnitude], thus averaging more strain (displacement) at audible frequencies. The resonant frequency itself doesn't matter (inaudible) but the rectification effect does. Because electro/magnetostriction is square-law. Y caps might also be piezoelectric, but I can't say I've ever heard them, and the small body and leads shouldn't couple very well acoustically.
